# adding a toolbar to a pickerview

Tags: iphone, picker

How I could able to add a toolbar to the picker? 
I want above the picker there is a toolbar with a "done" bar button item. clicking the "done" button will hide (animate) the picker offscreen (going to bottom like the keyboard)

I'm still looking for this how-to... Hope you could help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When I need to do this, I typically make a container view and place into it both the picker and the toolbar.  This allows the grouping to be hidden, moved, sized, etc as a unit.

```
UIView *pickerGroupView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: frame] autorelease];
thePicker.frame = pickerGroupView.bounds;
[pickerGroupView addSubview: thePicker];

theToolbar.center = pickerGroupView.center;  // assuming that's where you want it
[pickerGroupView addSubView: theToolbar];
```

Comment: Olie, i've tried your suggestion..but seems the picker and the toolbar (above the picker) is not aligned properly.. see the screenshots (http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/4043/screenshot20100608at450.png)
hope you can check my code (http://pastebin.com/XJZG9RWH)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make a new UIToolbar and position that directly above your picker view when you animate it in. Check out the [DateCell](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/DateCell) example for animation code.